# Velocity of rigid body on impact for sound effect?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

**How can I get the velocity of a rigid body *on impact* so that I can [add sound effects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/301845/168154)?**

[image]

`B-A`: if I get the velocity right before impact by comparing the last two frames before the z component switches direction (negative/positive), then it will be too high.

`C-B`: if I get the velocity before and after impact by comparing the frames before the z component switches direction (negative/positive) with the frame after the z component switches direction, then it will be too low.

`D-C`: if I get the velocity right after impact by comparing the next two frames after the z component switches direction (negative/positive), then it will be too high.

A rigid body simluation doesn't always have a frame that's touching on the floor, so I have left it unlabelled.

Comment: [get velocity](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235775/how-can-i-get-the-velocity-of-a-moving-rigid-body) and determine the impact frame and [add sound](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63834/how-to-add-sound-to-sequencer-using-python)